# Should I invest $35,000 for 3-5 months?

Tags: united-states, short-term

I have some savings ($35,000 USD) that I'll be living off of for the next 6-12 months. Is it possible to profit from some of this money in the short term before I need to access it?

Comment: The short answer is "No" Don't do that.

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/6778

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/83418

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to profit from some of this money in the short term before I need to access it?

Sure, it's **possible**.  But if the stock market decides to "correct" (or even crashes), you'll be in a world of hurt.

Thus, since it's so important that you not lose this money, just stick it in an online bank earning 1.2%, and withdraw "enough" twice a month.

EDIT: by "withdraw", I mean to transfer to your checking account.

Comment: My "high interest" money market account is only earning 0.3%....

Comment: @Michael of course, my answer is 3.5 years old.  (Also, Ally Bank savings account is 67% higher than your MM account, and there are even some which are 83% or more higher. :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and there are several ways, the safest is a **high-yield savings** account which will return about 1% yearly, so $35 per month. That's not extremely much, but better than nothing (you probably get almost zero interest on a regular checking account).

Comment: My how quickly answers such as this go out of date... my "high interest" money market account is now earning 0.3%... inflation is eating me alive